# Modifying variable within firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever my program attempts to modify `exists` in the `firebase function`, the obtained value is temporary. I want to be able to `return true` or `false` at the end of this `function`.I have seen a few related posts and nothing seems to be working. Making `exists global` and separating the `snapshot function` didnt work. Any advice?

```
function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
    var exists;
    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
    usersRef.child(userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        exists = (snapshot.val() !== null); // exists is true or false
        userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
    });
    return exists; //exists is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `once` returns a promise, and `then` returns a new promise, you can't just return `exists`, since the block that assigns a value to it happens later.

You can, however, return the promise, and use `then` in the call site

```
function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
    var exists;
    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
    return usersRef.child(userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        exists = (snapshot.val() !== null); // exists is true or false
        return exists;
    });
}
```

Then in the call site:

```
checkIfUserExists(userId).then(exists => /*do something*/)
```

Comment: Ok I am using it in a while loop so at the all site I would write what? checkIfUserExists(userId).then(exists => //how to return true or false)

Comment: If you're using it in a loop, you'll have many promises. You can use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to finish, and get a collection of results.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you cannot return exists because of the scope. Everything within the brackets after `function(snapshot)` is a callback, which means that your function sets up this query to the database and will run the code in those brackets after Firebase returns with your data. In the meantime, it will continue with the rest of your function. So exists isn't given a value before the return.

You probably want something more global. You could make exists a global variable, make this function return nothing, and check the value of exists afterwards. If you have to do this for multiple users, you can put it in a dictionary type of structure.